# How to re-select items in listbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web page that has two listbox.  I am having a problem with my jQuery/JavaScript.  When the user selects an item in the left listbox, it should select three items in the right listbox.  It only works the first time unless I refresh the page.  I know the code is being executed because I can step through it.  This seems to be a simple task so I must be missing something.  I created an online sample of the problem on [www.tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_jquery_editor.php) which shows the problem. [Listbox sample online](http://tpcg.io/RQoh44) - press the Preview button.  Thank you for your help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Re-select Items in Listbox</title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#meters').change(function () {
    $('#baselines option').prop('selected', false); // Clear selected baselines

    var data = [2, 3, 4];

    var len = $('#baselines option').length;

    for (var i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        $("#baselines option[value=" + i + "]").attr("selected", (data.indexOf(i) !== -1) ? true : false);
    }
});
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<p id="myid">Is is a test of selecting items in listbox</p>

<div>
  <select class="form-control" id="meters" name="SelectedMeters" style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="1">12345678</option>
    <option value="2">1234567890</option>
  </select>

  <select class="form-control" id="baselines" multiple="True" name="SelectedBaselines" size="10" style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="1">MeterBaseline1</option>
    <option value="2">MeterBaseline2</option>
    <option value="3">MeterBaseline3</option>
    <option value="4">MeterBaseline4</option>
    <option value="5">MeterBaseline5</option>
    <option value="6">MeterBaseline6</option>
    <option value="7">PJM_MovingAvg</option>
  </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use removeAttr for unselect the options and prop to select it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Try jQuery Online</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("em").addClass("selected");
   $("#myid").addClass("highlight");
   
   $('#meters').change(function () {
    $('#baselines option').removeAttr('selected');
    
    var data = [getRndInteger(1, 2),getRndInteger(3, 4),getRndInteger(5, 7)];
    
    console.debug(data);

    var len = $('#baselines option').length;

    for (var i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        $("#baselines option[value=" + i + "]").prop("selected", (data.indexOf(i) !== -1) ? true : false);
    }
});
});


</script>
<style>
.selected { 
    color:red; 
}
.highlight { 
    background:yellow; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="myid">Is is a test of selecting items in listbox</p>

<div>
  <select class="form-control" id="meters" name="SelectedMeters" style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="1">12345678</option>
    <option value="2">1234567890</option>
  </select>

  <select class="form-control" id="baselines" multiple="True" name="SelectedBaselines" size="10" style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="1">MeterBaseline1</option>
    <option value="2">MeterBaseline2</option>
    <option value="3">MeterBaseline3</option>
    <option value="4">MeterBaseline4</option>
    <option value="5">MeterBaseline5</option>
    <option value="6">MeterBaseline6</option>
    <option value="7">PJM_MovingAvg</option>
  </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked!  Thank you very much.  A dumb question, why didn't my way worked?

Comment: a pleasure to help you, what happened was that they were selected, only from the attribute

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the following line:

`$("#baselines option[value=" + i + "]").attr("selected", (data.indexOf(i) !== -1) ? true : false);`

To use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of using [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

`$("#baselines option[value=" + i + "]").prop("selected", (data.indexOf(i) !== -1) ? true : false);`

Comment: That worked!  Thank you.  Your links to prop and attr were helpful too.